# Custom template for platform add android

Tags: cordova-3

What is the best approach to create a customized template for platform add android?  We want to customize the www used and also the AndroidManifest.  We currently are using the top level www to customize www, but is this the best approach?  Is it possible / recommended to make a customized platform template?  If recommended, what is the best approach to set it up?

For AndroidManifest we want to default settings such as these:

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="portrait"  
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need this answer yet. But I was looking for something like it too today. And I found this link [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4911).

So, I think you can edit "platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml" and Cordova will keep your code. But if you still need to custom AndroidManifest, I think that you will need to edit AndroidManifest template from Cordova.

Regards,